# mongo gives error randomly MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

i used to connect to mongo instance using

```
mongoose.connect(MongoDBUri + "/" + dbname).then(() =>{
   console.log("connected to DB")
}).catch((err) => console.log("Error ===", err));
```

recently i updated this code to

```
(async () => {
const mongoUri = await (axios call);
const lookupDBName = await (axios call);
mongoose
  .connect(`${mongoUri}/${lookupDBName}`, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to DB");
   })
  .catch(err => {
   console.log("Error ===", err);
  });
})();
```

it worked fine on local and then also good on production environment. but on higher loads this started giving errors like:

> MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed

> MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false

> Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

these errors started coming after only adding the new options `useUnifiedTopology` and
`useNewUrlParser`.

the mongoose version i am using is `5.7.0`

i guess we should only use `useUnifiedTopology` with mongo instances containing replica sets. and as the second error says `not master and slaveOk=false`, my mongo instance does not contain replica sets, so we should not use the unifiedTopology option. - can this be the case here??

another strange issue noticed here was - while the express app deployed on prod server was not able to connect and get data from mongo, i was able to connect the Compass to view the data, and also on pointing the local server to mongo instance, i was getting the data. So, while the connection was available, the deployed express server was not able to connect to mongo.

also on reading this [article](https://technorach.wordpress.com/2021/02/13/pool-destroyed-lets-fix-this/), i tried using `reconnectTries` in options to increase the time limit for connection tries. but typescript didn't allowed me to add this option. although in [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect)  we have that option available.

Comment: I am sure you checked it, but for the records, do you confirm that `const mongoUri = await (axios call);` assigs the same string that you used in MongoDBUri  before the change? Do mongo logs have any clues?

Comment: yes it is same. if it was the issue with connection string, the app wouldn't have connected in the first place itself, but it connected. And after around 20-25 hours it loses the connection and unable to connect by giving above errors.

Comment: yes, I get it that it is sporadic. My point is the previous code had static url, whilst the new version retrieves the url runtime. It paves the path to have different values every time the code is executed. I'll speculate, but just to give you an idea - if there exception handling logic in the `axios call` is flawed, it **can** return an empty value, or anything non-connectable. It will result with exact symptoms you described - a connection timeout.

Comment: What about the database logs? do they have any failed connection attempts the time it fails on application level?